# Forward all traffic to new domain except keep homepage on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, forwarding

I have a website that was an Old website, forwarding to a new website. But on the old domain, I want to be able to use the homepage. It was set up with Wordpress, so perhaps keeping that setup would be good.

This is what I have for 301 forwarding to a new domain, but I need to keep it on the homepage as well as regular WordPress pages (ie: wp-admin)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If WordPress was installed at the root of the site (https://example.com), you won't be able to differentiate between the traffic for the two except via folders, or direct file access.

You can add file and directory exclusions like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So any visitor navigating to https://example.com/file.html will get the file directly, but all URIs pointing to existing directories or files will be redirected to newdomain.ca.

Comment: Right, so basically, if I'm able to remove WordPress, and just use a FILE based pages (ie: index.html) and route all traffic outside that file it might work.